# Very basic addon method not outputting anything

Tags: module, addons, newrelic

The following code is a small part of a module I've written for a client project. Can anyone see why in some templates it outputs the newrelic code but in others it doesn't?

```
function newrelic_stop() 
{
// Set defaults
$output = "";

if (extension_loaded('newrelic'))
{
    $output = newrelic_get_browser_timing_footer();
}

// Show the output
return $output;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to post the rest of the code...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that if I use an embed to output my opening newrelic code (method called newrelic_start in my addon), that outputs fine but stops the newrelic_stop tag from returning anything at all.

**The fix:** 
Use a stash embed instead! Doing this is not only a performance benefit over a traditional embed, but also gets my closing newrelic tag returning what it should.

Note that in the stash embed, you need to use process="inline"